# How to set the current time using NOW() formula in Excel without incrementing?

Tags: microsoft-excel, time

If I use `NOW()` in a formula it gives me the current time but next minutes it changes it's correct time or it's starts to continue.

But my question is current time should be hold without pressing the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

I need it in formula which holds the current time without continuing.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. Can you explain and provide more detail? Why do you need current time as formula? Why do you need to hold it? Until when should it hold it?

Comment: NOW() is dynamic; it will update whenever Excel recalculates.  You want a constant, and you need a way to insert that value at the specific time you require it.  You can't do that with a formula.  You will need VBA.  You can use NOW(), recalculate at the required time, then trigger a macro to copy, paste-special value.  Or you could trigger a macro to insert the current time as a constant.

Comment: I need it in my work tracker, once I start  with my work I will enter Ctrl+shift+; for current time and once I am done with my work I'll give end time and work status will be as "completed", so I need it to duration of my work but if I mentioned completed word. The end time should be taken by the formula by completed word from IF formula per my adjustment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do not refresh date in IF Statement using TODAY()](https://superuser.com/questions/1358758/do-not-refresh-date-in-if-statement-using-today)

Comment: Use `Ctrl+:` instead of a formula if you want static text

Comment: Your problem isn't clear.  You use Ctrl+Shift+; to insert the static time at the start and presumably at the finish.  The duration can use a formula.  You just subtract the start value from the finish value.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments `NOW()` is a volatile function, with each recalculation the value returned by `NOW()` is updated.

As a work around you can use 1 or 2 helper columns (depending on how your worksheet is setup) and some VBA to achieve this task.

- Column A (Start time)
- Column B (End Time)
- Column C (Formula e.g. **=TEXT(B1-A1, "h:mm")**)

You can use the below VBA code all you need to do is set it to the keyboard shortcut you want to use.

```vb
Sub insertTime()
    ' Assign this macro to a keyboard shortcut.
    ' e.g. [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[T]
    ' The currently selected cell will be updated with the time.

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range(ActiveCell.Address) ' Sets the currently selected cell as the range variable rng

    rng.Value = Now ' Changes the value of the selected cell to the timevalue

End Sub
```

How the above code works is explained in the comments included on each line.

Comment: no need to use VBA for this. [Excel already has the feature built-in](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-the-current-date-and-time-in-a-cell-b5663451-10b0-40ab-9e71-6b0ce5768138)